# P is linear orthogonal operator in E^3 such that detP=1, P(a)=-a. Show that P is a rotation operator around axis orthogonal to a.

Tags: geometry, vectors

Let P be linear orthogonal operator in E^3 such that detP=1, and for given non-zero vector a, P(a)=-a. Show that P is a rotation operator around axis orthogonal to a. Find angle of rotation.

Hi, I've just come across the question written above. I know that P is a rotation operator, as detP=1 so preserves orientation hence by Eulers Theorem it is a rotaion operator.

But I'm unsure how to calculate the axis of rotaion.

I presume you cannot assume that if P(a)=-a, then P(e)=-e, P(f)=-f, P(g)=-g ?

Thanks in advance for your help!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the axis of rotation is going to be along the eigenvector, whose corresponding eigenvalue is 1, i.e along the vector which is preserved. Since P is orthogonal, we can see that for any vector b perpendicular to 'a'

we have,  a . b = 0 
then P(a) . P(b)=0 due to orthogonality which implies

-a . P(b) = 0 
 a . P(b) = 0.. it means that any vector perpendicular to 'a' remains perpendicular to a.. i.e. stays on the same line.

So, this perpendicular line is preserved under rotation, so this is the axis. And since we are sending a to -a, it is just a rotation by 180 degrees.

Answer (score 0):

Hint:

since $P a=-a$,  $a$ is an eigenvector of $P$ for the eigenvalue $-1$. A rotation in $\mathbb{R}^3$ has three eigenvalues: $1,e^{\pm i\theta}$ where $\theta$ is the angle of rotation, so you can find $\theta$, and the eigenspace of the eigenvalue $1$ ( the fixed points, i.e. the axis of rotation) is orthogonal to the eigenvector $a$.